# Ruby: return the name of the lowest variable

Tags: ruby

I want to return the id of the lowest value from a hash:

```
{var1:345 , var2:764 , var3:126 }.return_lowest_value_id => "var3"
```

What is the most elegant Ruby way to do this without IF statements?

Comment: Why do you care about the variable name, rather than the value?

Comment: it is an "id" of the var value. maybe this needs to be a hash? like:
`{var1:345 , var2:764 , var3:126 }.return_lowest_value_id => "var3"`

Comment: This is a common beginner question and it's really not something you ever need to do.  Don't design your code to rely on variable names.

Comment: yes thanks, thats why I wanted to ask you guys, it's now a hash in my program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of using hash, you can try this:

```
{var1:345 , var2:764 , var3:126 }.sort_by { |k, v| v }.first[0]  # => :var3
```

As an another option, you can use `min_by` method:

```
{var1:345 , var2:764 , var3:126 }.min_by { |k, v| v }[0]  # => :var3
```

Comment: Kieran, what behavior do yo want if there are two or more variables with the same lowest value?

Comment: they can choose the first in the row, as long as there is one returned